# New to coding and would like some pointers regarding my Objective C code

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I'm working my way through Stephan Kochan's book on Objective C and I've come up against a problem which I'm hoping someone can help with.

Here's my print method from a Fraction class that I've been working on:

```
-(void) print: (BOOL) reduce {
Fraction *resultReduced = [[Fraction alloc] init];
[resultReduced setTo:numerator over:denominator];

if (denominator < 0) {
    numerator = -numerator;
    denominator = -denominator;
}    
if (reduce) {
    [resultReduced reduce];
    if (resultReduced.denominator < 0) {
        resultReduced.denominator = -resultReduced.denominator;
        resultReduced.numerator = -resultReduced.numerator;
    }
    else if (resultReduced.denominator == 1)
        NSLog (@"%i", resultReduced.numerator);
    else if (resultReduced.numerator == 0)
        NSLog (@"0");
    else if (resultReduced.numerator == resultReduced.denominator)
        NSLog (@"1");
    else if (resultReduced.numerator > resultReduced.denominator || resultReduced.numerator < 0) {
        [resultReduced improper];
        if (resultReduced.whole == 0)
            NSLog (@"%i/%i", resultReduced.numerator, resultReduced.denominator);
        else if (resultReduced.whole < 0 && resultReduced.numerator < 0) {
            resultReduced.numerator = -resultReduced.numerator;
            NSLog (@"%i %i/%i", resultReduced.whole, resultReduced.numerator, resultReduced.denominator);             
        }
        else
            NSLog (@"%i %i/%i", resultReduced.whole, resultReduced.numerator, resultReduced.denominator);
    }
    else
        NSLog (@"%i/%i", resultReduced.numerator, resultReduced.denominator);
}
else
    NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
```

}

The problem is that if I subtract 15/4 from 2/3 I get -37/12 which I'd like to display as -3 1/12 using this message [resultReduced improper] but it doesn't appear to work.  If I change

`else if (resultReduced.numerator > resultReduced.denominator || resultReduced.numerator < 0) {`

to just if then it does.

Could someone please explain to me why using if works, but if else doesn't?

Comment: You should be able to find the problem by stepping through your program in the debugger.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this?

Comment: [Here's a link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html) to the docs on debugging in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "if" statement by itself will execute every time. The "else" will only execute if the "if" fails.

Comment: Okay but I still don't get why using else if doesn't work where as if does.  Sorry like I said I'm totally new to coding and I'm still struggling with the basics.

Comment: Because the denominator is greater than 0 then it moves down to check whether its equal to one.  As it isn't it then moves down to check if its equal to 0 which it isn't.  Then it moves down to check if its the same as the denominator, which again it isn't.  So how come then it doesn't move down to the one I'm struggling with unless I use if and not else if?

Comment: Also I tried using else if (resultReduced.numerator < 0) but that didn't work either and I don't understand why as -37/12 means that the numerator is less than 0 so surely it should have therefor run the code.

Comment: This is why you need to try it in the debugger as suggested above. You need to see what values you're actually getting to see how the program control flows.

Comment: Okay I went through the debugger and I'm still not sure whats happening.  If I multiply -2/3 by 13/4 I get -26/12 but when it runs through "if (reduce)" it gets to "if (resultReduced.denominator < 0)" and then for some reason, even though the denominator is 12 and therefor not less then 0, it executes that if statement and then jumps out of the reduce loop and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Never mind I triple checked and for some reason the numerator is 26 and the denominator is -12.  I'll take a look at rest of my code and try to work out whats happening.  Thanks for all your help.